# Where is the syntax error in this dictionary? [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, string, syntax, dictionary

I'm not sure why this code isn't working. . . I can't find the syntax error it seems fine . It is in the same format as all my other dictionaries

> > > d=dict(zip(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'),('6','10.76','5.41'.'2.71','5.07','5.65','3.22','5.97','7.59','6.02','6.02','9.74','5.74','5.48','6.3','5.68','2.09','5.89','5.66','5.96')))
> > >              ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The arrow is pointing to the '5.68' on the decimal .

Comment: Time to close as too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a '.' where there should be a ',' at '5.41'.'2.71'

Answer (score 3):

`'5.41'.'2.71'` should be `'5.41', '2.71'`

BTW, you should break big lines in small ones:

```
keys = ['A', 'B', 'C',
        'X', 'Y', 'Z']
values = [1.0, 2.1, 3.2,
          4.3, 5.4, 6.5]
d = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Comment: @O.rka The way I just did. Be sure to close all parens and use commas, not periods between strings... BTW are you doing the same work since 2011???

Comment: i was just learning how to use python in 2011 and i was going through my old questions to look for something.  for some reason i've tried this before and it wouldn't let me split them in my IDE without errors